# Mayavi doesn't run from within Spyder: complains about "ValueError: API 'QString' ..."

Tags: python, mayavi, spyder

I am unable to run/use Mayavi library from within Spyder IDE. I have described the problem below. Any help will be very useful. (Thank you very much in advance.)

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Just importing the Mayavi library in a script (for example using "import mayavi.mlab as mlab") and executing the script will reproduce this problem.
2. I am including a test code (note that this code is an example code from the Mayavi website) here to reproduce the problem:

## code

```
from numpy import sin, cos, mgrid
import mayavi.mlab as mmlab

def f(x,y):
  return sin(x + y) + sin(2*x - y) + cos(3*x + 4*y)
        
x,y = mgrid[-7.:7.05:0.01, -5.:5.05:0.05]
z = f(x,y)
s = mmlab.contour_surf(x,y,z)
mmlab.show()
```

**Expected output and the Error:**

Expected output: A Mayavi figure window with the figure.
What I see instead: The following Value error (I am including the full sequence of message in order to be explicit)in the console window:

*-------------------------- Beginning of error message ------------------*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRAMSANDEXPERIMENTS\PYTHON\MayaviScripts\Learning\testMayavi.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mayavi.mlab as mmlab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 25, in <module>
    from engine_manager import get_engine
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mayavi.preferences.api import preference_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from preference_manager import preference_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
    from traitsui.api import View, Group, Item
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\api.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .editors.api import (ArrayEditor, BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .api import (toolkit, ArrayEditor, BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .code_editor import CodeEditor
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\code_editor.py", line 36, in <module>
    class ToolkitEditorFactory ( EditorFactory ):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\code_editor.py", line 48, in ToolkitEditorFactory
    mark_color = Color( 0xECE9D8 )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\traits.py", line 487, in __call__
    return self.maker_function( *args, **metadata )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\traits.py", line 1183, in Color
    return ColorTrait( *args, **metadata )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit_traits.py", line 7, in ColorTrait
    return toolkit().color_trait( *args, **traits )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py", line 109, in toolkit
    _toolkit = _import_toolkit(ETSConfig.toolkit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py", line 51, in _import_toolkit
    return __import__( name, globals=globals(), level=1 ).toolkit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitsui\qt4\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pyface.qt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyface\qt\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    prepare_pyqt4()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyface\qt\__init__.py", line 17, in prepare_pyqt4
    sip.setapi('QString', 2)
  ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 1
```

*---------------------------- End of error message --------------------*

**My environment(s) are the following:**

This issue has been observed at-least in the following two environments:

### Environment 1:

Description: Spyder and all other components were installed using the Pythonxy distribution (Py(x,y)-2.7.2.3.exe) on a Windows 7, 32 bit machine).
Spyder Version:  2.1.9
Python Version:  2.7.2 (32 bit)
Qt Version:      4.7.4, PyQt4 (API v1) 4.8.6 on Windows
Mayavi Version:  4.1.0

### Environment 2:

Description: On a separate machine running 64 bit Windows 7, I have installed 64-bit version of the Enthought EPD distribution. So it is running 2.7.3 (x64) version of Python distribution. Since the EPD package doesn't include Spyder, I manually installed Spyder after installing PyQt GPLv4.9.4.
Spyder Version:  2.1.11
Python Version:  2.7.3 (64 bit)
Qt Version:      4.8.2, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.9.4 on Windows
Mayavi Version:  4.2.0

**Additional information:**

I am sure that the code is fine, as the script produces the expected output when executed "outside" spyder environment. For example, using IPython shell.

Thank you.

Comment: That code is indeed fine. This error occurs if one tries to set the PyQt api with `sip.setapi` _after_ PyQt is imported. Mayavi is trying to set that but apparently Spyder imports/uses PyQt already for the shell. This looks like a bug on Spyder side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Avaris for your response.

I have a solution for now (I am not sure of it as a "fix"). I modified the following setting in `Tools->Preferences->Console->External Modules->Enthought Tool Suite->ETS_TOOLKIT`: change from `Qt4` to `wx`.
After changing this setting, I am able to execute code with Mayavi library and Mayavi plots directly from within Spyder.

Answer (score 3):

for linux users, the answer by `imranal` in [this issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708292/valueerror-cannot-set-toolkit-to-wx-because-it-has-already-been-set-to-qt4) can be referenced to.

just add `export ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4` to a new line in `~/.bashrc` will do the trick.
don't forget to `source` the `~/.bashrc` file!

Comment: OP explicitly mentions target system as Windows.

Comment: @SergeyA  sorry, but I am myself a Linux user and encountered exactly the same problem. After I googled it, I found this issue on SO. Since python is cross-platform, I'm definitely sure some other linux user will be here. And I think they have the RIGHT to know what to do to debug. I'm just doing a favour.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spyderlib/NqNbrsdMoUQ) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/source/detail?r=4fb9a89c6320719280b87b6583823cb9e7736432) the error can be fixed by activating the `Ignore API change errors (sip.setapi)` checkbox in `Preferences > Console > External Modules`.

I have tested that it does work with Spyder 2.1.11.